# Propel Saving: naming convention

Tags: php, propel

I am having troubles with the casing of variables in Propel

Current code that works:

```
$this->_variables = array('Alias' => 'aliasOne', 'LocationId' => 1);
$model = new Client();
$model->fromArray($this->_variables);
$model->save();
```

However due to the format of my API output, I would prefer the code to be

```
$array = array('alias' => 'aliasOne', 'location_id' => 1);
$model = new Client();
$model->fromArray($array);
$model->save();
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Yes, the second one doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

It's already handled by Propel thanks to the second argument of the method `fromArray()`:

```
$array = array('alias' => 'aliasOne', 'location_id' => 1);
$model = new Client();
$model->fromArray($array, BasePeer::TYPE_FIELDNAME);
$model->save();
```

See the definition of this constant, and other constants here: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/runtime/lib/util/BasePeer.php#L63

Answer (score 0):

You can make a proxy `fromArray` in the Client model with a map array to convert your keys, in your `lib/model/om/BaseClient.php`:

```
public function myFromArray($arr, $keyType = BasePeer::TYPE_PHPNAME)
{
  $map = array(
    'alias'       => 'Alias',
    'location_id' => 'LocationId',
    // you can add more
  );

  $newArr = array();
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
  {
    // replace the key with the good one
    if (array_key_exists($key, $map))
    {
      $newArr[$map[$key]] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
      $newArr[$key] = $value;
    }
  }

  $this->fromArray($newArr, $keyType);
}
```